# Copy data from sheets in one workbook to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

In a workbook, say `Main.xlsx`, I have multiple sheets say `Main418, Main418_NotBilled, Main923, Main923_NotBilled`.

At another location I have two workbooks say, `Wokbook_418.xlsx` and `Wokbook_923.xlsx`. In `Wokbook_418.xlsx` there are three sheets `Total, Sheet418, Sheet418_NotBilled`. Similarly in `Wokbook_923.xlsx` there are three sheets `Total, Sheet923, Sheet923_NotBilled`.

My requirement is to have a `macro in Main.xlsx`, which needs to copy two workbooks `"Wokbook_418.xlsx" and "Wokbook_923.xlsx"` to another location with names  `Wokbook_418_copy_26May.xlsx and Wokbook_923_copy_26May.xlsx respectively`.

Now in "`Wokbook_418_copy_26May.xlsx`",
- do not want to touch Total sheet.
- want to replace data in sheet "`Sheet418`" with the data in sheet "`Main418`". (sheet "Main418" is available in Main.xlsx)
- want to replace data in sheet "`Sheet418_NotBilled`" with the data in sheet "`Main418_NotBilled`". (sheet "Main418_NotBilled" is available in Main.xlsx)

And  in "`Wokbook_923_copy_26May.xlsx`",
- do not want to touch Total sheet.
- want to replace data in sheet "`Sheet923`" with the data in sheet "`Main923`". (sheet "Main923" is available in Main.xlsx)
- want to replace data in sheet "`Sheet923_NotBilled`" with the data in sheet "`Main923_NotBilled`". (sheet "Main923_NotBilled" is available in Main.xlsx)

I do not have expertise of this level in excel.

I need some guidance (not the exact code) to achieve this functionality.

Please help in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a macro in your Main.xlsx workbook, you can open each workbook, copy information from your sheets inside the Main.xlsx, and then have the edited workbooks saved to a new location with your naming criteria.  For example:

```
Sub Macro1()

'opens the Workbook_418.xlsx file
Workbooks.Open Filename:="your_file_path_here\Workbook_418.xlsx"

'Activates your Main.xlsx workbook
Windows("Main.xlsx").Activate

'Selects your Main418 worksheet and copies the entire sheet
    Sheets("Main418").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy

'Activates your Workbook_418.xlsx workbook
Windows("Workbook_418.xlsx").Activate

'Selects your Sheet418 worksheet and pastes the entire sheet
    Sheets("Sheet418").Select
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

'Saves the Workbook_418.xlsx file with your new file name
    'formats a string to return the day & month
    Dim x As String
x = Day(Date) & MonthName(Month(Date))

Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="your_file_path_here\Workbook_418_" & x & ".xlsx", _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank very much for your help in this. I am able to perform the operation with one sheet. I will update the macro to read and save the contents of all the sheets. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Using guidance provided by @Dave in above response, I have created it for all the sheets. I am posting solution here just to help other:

```
Sub Macro1()


   Dim LCounter As Integer

   For LCounter = 1 To 4

        'BUNumber should be 417, 618, 641, 682
            If LCounter = 1 Then
                 BUNumber = 417
            ElseIf LCounter = 2 Then
                BUNumber = 618
            ElseIf LCounter = 3 Then
                BUNumber = 641
            ElseIf LCounter = 4 Then
                BUNumber = 682
            End If

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' File Operation Start'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'opens the Reference_BU417.xlsx file
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\makumar\Desktop\file for mani\reference_files\Reference_BU" & BUNumber & ".xlsx"

        'Activates your Main sheet.xlsm workbook
        Windows("Main sheet.xlsm").Activate

            'Selects your 417 worksheet and copies the entire sheet
                Sheets("" & BUNumber & "").Select
                Cells.Select
                Selection.Copy

        'Activates your Reference_BU417.xlsx workbook
        Windows("Reference_BU" & BUNumber & ".xlsx").Activate

            'Selects your BU417 worksheet and pastes the entire sheet
                Sheets("BU" & BUNumber & "").Select
                Cells.Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste




        'Activates your Main sheet.xlsm workbook
        Windows("Main sheet.xlsm").Activate

            'Selects your 417_NotBilled worksheet and copies the entire sheet
                Sheets("" & BUNumber & "_NotBilled").Select
                Cells.Select
                Selection.Copy

        'Activates your Reference_BU417.xlsx workbook
        Windows("Reference_BU" & BUNumber & ".xlsx").Activate

            'Selects your BU417_NotBilled worksheet and pastes the entire sheet
                Sheets("BU" & BUNumber & "_NotBilled").Select
                Cells.Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste




        'Saves the Reference_BU417.xlsx file with your new file name
            With ActiveWorkbook
                .SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\makumar\Desktop\file for mani\generated_files\" & _
                            Left(.Name, InStrRev(.Name, ".") - 1) & _
                            "_" & Format(Date, "ddmmmyyyy") & ".xlsx"
            End With


        'closes the Reference_BU417.xlsx file
        Workbooks("Reference_BU" & BUNumber & ".xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''File Operation End'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


      MsgBox ("Complete for: " & BUNumber & "")

   Next LCounter


End Sub
```